# Shouldn't "much" here be used instead of "more"?

Tags: comparative-degree

I read a sentence in a chapter named "The Last Lesson" which was:

> It was because they were sorry, too, that they had not gone to school **more**.

*More* is a comparative adjective. So I wonder in the sentence, it is not clear 'more than what?'. I think it has been used in a wrong way here and the author wanted to convey the sense of *much*. Am I right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case, it's referring to the number of times they *did* go to school. The *more* is in comparison to whatever the reality of the situation actually is.

For instance:

> However many vegetables you eat, you can always eat *more*.

Or, in the sentence in question:

> It was because they were sorry, too, that they had not gone to school more ***[than they did]***.

The explicitly missing words are generally assumed to exist.

Answer (score 7):

> It was because they were sorry, too, that they had not gone to school more.

This is a grammatical sentence whose meaning is clear. When *more* is used this way - “they didn’t do X more” it means “they didn’t do X more than they did”. To be more explicit, for this particular sentence:

> It was because they were sorry, too, that they had not gone to school ***more than they had gone to school***.

It would be redundant to say (or write) that whole sentence; *more* by itself conveys this meaning.

*not much* is different - it just means “not a lot”. In this context they were probably sorry they had not gone to school *much* but we don’t know that for sure. Maybe they did go to school *much* of the time, but still regretted not going to school more than they did.

Comment: +1 for explaining the difference in meaning that "much" would have.